# Calculate difference between two poses

Tags: ros, pose, quaternion, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I running in to a problem calculating the difference between two tf poses. Currently I calculate the difference by subtracting the X, Y and Z (orientation) of pose 1 from pose 2. This works fine. Only when I try to do the same for the rotation (XYZW) the result is (sometimes) NaN. Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to calculate the difference between two poses?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60658/calculate-difference-between-two-poses/) by [Robbiepr1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4154/robbiepr1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2013-04-14

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-04-14**:
Are you using the c++ tf method? Sometimes a transform is not available yet, you can use waitForTransform(). Try also to print out the numbers you are subtracting.

**Comment by [Robbiepr1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4154/robbiepr1/) on 2013-04-14**:
Thanks for your reply. The situation is that I already have two poses (both of type tf::Stamped<tf::Pose> and can even have the same frame_id) and I want to get the difference between those two poses. I already printed the numbers I'm subtracting and they seem valid numbers.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-04-14**:
First of all, you cannot simply subtract two rotations, since they (and the result) must be valid quaternions; for example, sqrt(x^2 + y^2 +z^2 +w^2) must be = 1. Still, you should only get NaN after subtraction if one (or both) of the input values are already NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

TF provides a correct way for this:

```
tfpose1.inverseTimes(tfpose2)
```

This is the transformation from pose1 to pose2 or "pose2 - pose1" (with the '-' not being a real minus, but the correct operator).
The resulting pose will have a transformation and orientation that is the difference of the two poses.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 18

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robbiepr1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4154/robbiepr1/) on 2013-04-15**:
Thanks, that did the trick

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2015-08-11**:
How does this even work when you are using Pose from geometry_msgs?

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2015-12-20**:
@Mehdi.

You can do the same by converting geometry_msgs Pose to tf Transform using the file tf/transform_datatypes.h which defines these data type transformations.

**Comment by [i_robot_flight](https://answers.ros.org/users/32131/i_robot_flight/) on 2017-11-10**:
Just to clarify my understanding, does this transform pose2 to the pose1 reference frame? The new pose data is written to pose1? Thanks!

**Comment by [sanazir](https://answers.ros.org/users/32401/sanazir/) on 2017-11-26**:
any idea how to do this in python?

**Comment by [simff](https://answers.ros.org/users/31951/simff/) on 2018-02-21**:
@Robbiepr1 How did you save the result of your subtraction? For me using subtract = tfpose1.inverseTimes(tfpose2) did not work! I would also need that method too.
Anyone knows?